# How to configure and use rsyncd?

Tags: rsync

I have a server configured to run rsync as demon
/etc/rsyncd.conf file:

```
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock

[documents]
   path = /home/user/work
   comment = User's Documents folder
   uid = user
   gid = user
   read only = no
   auth users = user
   secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

/etc/rsyncd.secrets file:

```
user:more
```

on the client side I run:

```
rsync my_file user@ip_address::documents
```

and I receive the following error:

```
@ERROR: auth failed on module documents
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1524) [sender=3.0.7]
```

On the server I have a root user named user with different password. On the client side
I tried both passwords with the same results.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In order to use rsync as a deamon I use
[documents]
   path = /home/user/work
   comment = User's Documents folder
   read only = no
    . Without a user and authentication.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are wanting to use rsyncd?  It is far easier and more secure using rsync via ssh like this:  `rsync -avP /source user@host:/destination`

Comment: @UtahJarhead I don't know about the OP, but in my case, transferring 5-10  2TB chunks compressed of files across a stub network means that I don't care about the security of the transfer. I want every available byte going down the wire. Extra protocol overhead and encryption of traffic that I don't need. A few kps lost means a few hours on the far end of the job. rsync generates an on the fly checksum that validates the transfer which is separate from the -c option for comparing existing files.

Comment: @RowanHawkins Quite right, mate!  That's about the only reason to use rsyncd over rsync+ssh.  However, the overhead from ssh likely won't affect the transfer speed unless weak CPUs are involved.  Encryption + weak CPUs = bleh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the same error and when Im looking in the log file I get this message:

> secrets file must not be other-accessible

So probably you have to change the permission of the file.

Comment: chmod -o /etc/rsyncd.conf

Answer (score 5):

Look in /var/log/rsyncd.log. Maybe the perms in your "/etc/rsyncd.secrets
" file are too wide.

Comment: 2011/03/01 11:49:07 [13367] connect from user2.local (192.168.0.196)
2011/03/01 11:49:10 [13367] auth failed on module work from user2.local (192.168.0.196): unauthorized user
in /etc/rsyncd.secrets file I added:
user2:passwd
user2.local:passwd

But same result.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by schemanen is correct, however you have the option to disable strict modes in rsyncd.conf without removing read permissions from the secrets file from other users.

in your /etc/rsyncd.conf add:

```
strict modes = false
```

and finally restart the rsync daemon.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the entry from rsync.conf for "auth user = user", and restarted rsyncd. Use of "auth" forces the challenge password to be entered despite use of a secrets file.  And, though I had the same password in user/password pair in the secrets file, it still failed with the error you indicated.  Removing "auth user" was my solution. The permissions on my secrets file: "500". Cronjob on client executed as root.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be a space in front of the password:

- Wrong: `user: password`
- Right: `user:password`

As the others said, you also have to make sure the permissions are set correctly (`chmod o-rwx`) but this is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to look for, and this is what was killing my setup.

DO NOT use :rw after the user name in the auth users line unless your version of rsync supports it. The man page for 3.1.2 I found at download.samba.org has the :rw option for users in the 'auth users' line, however the 3.0.9 version that I had on an older Mint doesn't yet have :rw.  I wasted a lot of time trying to get rsyncd to work - took off the ':rw' and bang!  It worked perfectly.  (Of course, a better solution would be to update that computer - which is planned..)

Also, in my case, if I didn't have the auth users line, no password would be asked for - which was not acceptable for my setup.  I'm curious as to how it worked for @mthebie99 to get the password prompt.  Unless, of course, @mthebie99 was using a version where it works right (or at least as I would have expected).